# How to monitor process creation and exit, and module loading on linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

On windows,these jobs can be done by using PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine and PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine.But I want to realize it on linux.Can anyone give some advice or ideas?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, this site is programming related. In that case, your question does not have any problem related to programming or as such. So the chances of getting help are less. Since, you tagged it as `linux`, you can ask the same question at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe  I didn't describe clearly. I didn't mean to find a tool.What I want to do is implementing a linux kernel module with functions above . The version of windows has finished by using wdk api PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine and PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine.

Answer (score 2):

For catch module's loading event you need to use `register_module_notifier()` function. Its `struct notifier_block` argument should be initialized before call:

```
int notifier_callback(struct notifier_block *nb,
     unsigned long action, void *data)
{
    struct module* m = data; // Module which state is changed.
    switch(action)
    {
    case MODULE_STATE_COMING:
        // Module is just loaded
    break;
    case MODULE_STATE_LIVING:
        // Module's init function has been executed
    break;
    case MODULE_STATE_GOING:
        // Module's exit function has been executed
    break;
    }

    return 0;
}

struct notifier_block n =
{
    .notifier_call = &notifier_callback,
    .priority = <any integer value, e.g. 0>
};

...

int my_module_init(void)
{
      ...
      register_module_notifier(&n);
}

void my_module_exit(void)
{
      unregister_module_notifier(&n);
      ...
}
```

I don't know any way for monitoring process's state.